# MongoDB - NodeJS - loosing ObjectId when serializing to JSON

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Trying to write / export some data from MongoDB to a file, where later I'd like to read/update them back.

```
    filehandle = await fs.promises.open(params.credentialsFilename, 'w');
    // ... some other code
    let records= await mongoConn.db(params.db).collection(COLLECTION_RECORDS)
         .find({}).toArray();
    for(const anObj of records) {
        console.log('[exportMongoDbWriteToFile] writing _id: ', anObj._id);
        console.log(anObj);
        await filehandle.write(JSON.stringify(anObj, null, 2)); // start array
        // await filehandle.write(anObj); // doesn't work with an object
    }
```

Th problem is that `JSON.stringify(anObj)` converts the `ObjectId(hex_id)` to a string of `hex_id` for the `_id` property (for any property using the *ObjectId* reference).

This is a problem as reading the data back to the MongoDB the string `hex_id` is not/ is different than `ObjectId(hex_id)` (as far I know).

However `console.log(anObj);` actually writes the full JSON with the ObjectId notation, not sure how the object is serialized for the console, we'd like to have the same output written into the file too.

Edit: we're using the default `mongodb` library

Comment: You can use `mongoexport` command-line tool to export MongoDB data to a JSON file. You can import the same JSON file using `mongoimport`. These tools convert the `ObjectId` properly (with [Extended JSON](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/)).